# How do I show an image in 1 column Magento home page

Tags: xml, magento

i want to show an image on my magento home page. How do I do this?

Here's the current code of my homepage. I want to show the image at the top. As you can see I tried it with some code. (sorry I'm a real noob concerning this stuff.)

```
<action method="setImgSrc"><src>http://www.doozoo.com/skin/frontend/exdress/default/images/cdd_delivery_promoter.png</src></action>
<reference name="slideshow">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_slideshow">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>slideshow</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="brands_slider">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_brandsslider">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>brands_slider</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
 <reference name="products_slider">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_productsslider">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>products_slider</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="dailytopproduct">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_dailytopproduct">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>daily_top_product</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="exdressme">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_exdressme">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>exdressme</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
<remove name="delivery_promoter" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Magento backend, CMS - Manage Pages and edit homepage there.

Comment: I got that far. I tried editing the Contents, and layout section of the homepage. But no results. Also after refreshing the cache.

Comment: You should be more clear in your questions. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways,

1. Go to Admin panel, `CMS -> Pages -> Home Page -> from left select "content"`. Use the image icon of editor to upload images.
2. `<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>images/cdd_delivery_promoter.png`

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to give a good answer as it also depends on where you want the image to show up and how you already customized the homepage. Looking at your layout XML it looks like it is already customized a lot.

The most general answer I can give you to add a custom image to the content block on the homepage is by changing the following in the `page.xml` layout XML file:

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
  <label>CMS Home Page</label>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text" name="homepage_custom_image" before="-">
      <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<img src="/path/to/image.png" width="400" height="100" alt="Alt Text Here" />]]></text>
      </action>
    </block>
  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

This will put the image on top of the page, with the other content from the CMS below it.

Comment: I think that will do the trick, thanks! I indeed want to show it above the slide show...